# Is SonarQube's MSBuild scanner compatible with Silverlight 5?

Tags: c#, msbuild, sonarqube, silverlight-5.0, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to get metrics on a legacy Silverlight application. The MSBuild scanner seems to find issues, but the lines of code count is way off. It is reporting ~300 LOC, when the sonar scanner finds ~250,000 LOC. If that is the only problem, then I can deal with it. But, the LOC being off doesn't give me a lot of confidence.

It seems you could configure the sonar scanner by setting an mscorlib location parameter: sonar.silverlight.5.mscorlib.location. I haven't been able to find anything comparable for the MSBuild scanner.

Is there some configuration I am missing?

Comment: The distinction you're making between the "MSBuild scanner" (SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild?) versus the "sonar scanner" is unclear. Are you contrasting the behavior of SonarQube Scanner against that of SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild?

Comment: @GAnnCampbell That is correct. I have been able to run both against my .NET projects, but my understanding is that SonarQube Scanner is deprecated and SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild should be used for .NET. However, SonarQube Scanner got more accurate LOC for my Silverlight project. SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild was incorrect, which makes me concerned I didn't have it configured properly for Silverlight projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C# projects, the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild is both preferred and recommended. It is designed to understand the layout of a C# project, recognize its pieces, and handle proper configuration of the analysis.

For other types of projects (E.G. those Java projects built with Maven or Gradle), other scanners are recommended. For a Silverlight project you should use the default/fallback [SonarQube Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner)